Problem with UV Transfer in Geometry Nodes
I'll start saying that I have a very procedural geometry, so I need to transfer UVs in geometry nodes.
Basically I tried to transfer these UVS:

That get transfered correctlty on the remeshed mesh, but keep these jagged edges that I need to fix:

I tried several ways, but nothing seems to work. I think the problem is due to the Domain of the Attribute of the UVs, which is Face Corner, but I have no idea how I can prevent this error. This was my setup:

Any possible solutions?
I've also uploaded a .blend file here with this problem:
https://we.tl/t-Wx6JA4tbHs
Thanks.
EDIT:
The deformations I'm trying to get rid of come mostly from connected edges between the UV islands that it's creating.

I have a better result by applying a Data Transfer Modifier and setting it to "Nearest Face Interpolated", for example.

I'm mostly looking for a solution to achieve this desired result but in geometry nodes instead of using a Data Transfer.

I don't think this can be solved, if you remesh an object you lose UV resolution and UVs seams will be interpolated. The only way you won't see these seams is to make sure you have an edge ring exactly where the Uv seam lies, and that in itself is quite a challenge. Have you considered baking the UVs to the remeshed mesh ?

BTW I touched up a bit about this subject over there https://blenderartists.org/t/gorgious-photogrammetry-shenanigans/1454287?u=gorgious

Hello, thanks for looking into this issue! Unfortunately I would really need a solution in Geometry nodes because there are several modifiers before and after this step that I'm having a problem with, and I would really like to keep this all procedural. I think the result can be at least improved, I don't need the edges to be perfectly straight like in the original mesh, but I simply need for it to interpolate the faces in a better way. I'll edit the post with a few more screenshots to better describe my problem and the desired result.
